# How do i get navigation extras from router.events.subscribe?

Tags: angular

I implemented

```
import { Router } from '@angular/router';
...
constructor(router: Router) {
    router.events.subscribe(event => {
        ...
    });
}
```

and **I want to get the `replaceUrl` value from `NavigationExtras`** that you set with `<a [routerLink]="..." replaceUrl="true"></a>` or `this.router.navigate(['...'], {replaceUrl: true})` .

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
import { Router } from '@angular/router';
...
constructor(router: Router) {
    router.events.subscribe(event => {
        console.log(router.getCurrentNavigation().extras?.replaceUrl);
    });
}
```